# Make file name Date in android

Tags: android, file

I have an app that backs up a database like so:

```
// Method To Backup Database//
public void OnClick_Backup(View v) {

    // Vibrates For 50 Mill//
    vibe.vibrate(50);

    int a = Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR;

    int b = Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;

    File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/C.S. Tracker Backups");
    if(!sd.exists()){
        sd.mkdirs();
    }
        try {
            File sd2 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd2.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//jordanzimmittidevelopers.com.communityservicelogger//databases//community_service_Database";
                String backupDBPath = "/C.S. Tracker Backups/C.S. Backup";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd2, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup is successful to SD card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
```

This code right here tells what path it should right the database file to:

```
   String backupDBPath = "/C.S. Tracker Backups/C.S. Backup";
```

How do I get C.S. Backup to change to the date it is when the backup was made. For instance, say they click backup now. I want it to say 4-21-15. Thaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat class to get the result that you want.

```
SimpleDateFormat mFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String backupDBPath =  mFormatter.format(c.getTime());
```